# Move sub nodes into parent attributes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML which contains records and sub records, like this:

```
<data>
    <record jsxid="id0x0b60fec0" ID="12429070" Created="2008-10-21T03:00:00.0000000-07:00">
        <record jsxid="id0x0b60ff10" string="101"/>
        <record jsxid="id0x0e64d8e8" string="63"/>
        <record jsxid="id0x2fd83f08" string="Y"/>
    </record>
    <record jsxid="id0x0b60fec0" ID="12429070" Created="2008-10-21T03:00:00.0000000-07:00">
        <record jsxid="id0x0b60ff10" string="102"/>
        <record jsxid="id0x0e64d8e8" string="77"/>
        <record jsxid="id0x2fd83f08" string="Y"/>
    </record>       
<data>
```

I need to transform it so that the string attribute of the sub records are brought up into the parent record as consecutively numbered attributes and then discarded, like this:

```
<data>
    <record jsxid="id0x0b60fec0" ID="12429070" Created="2008-10-21T03:00:00.0000000-07:00" 1="101" 2="63" 3="Y"/>
    <record jsxid="id0x0b60fec0" ID="12429070" Created="2008-10-21T03:00:00.0000000-07:00" 1="102" 2="77" 3="Y"/>
<data>
```

The number of sub-records is arbitrary across documents but remains static within the same document.

Would someone be so kind as to point the way to an XSLT solution? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a complete solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- By default, recursively copy all nodes unchanged -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- But don't process any children of <record> (such as whitespace)... -->
  <xsl:template match="record/node()"/>

  <!-- ...except for doubly-nested records;
       convert them to attributes, named according to position -->
  <xsl:template match="record/record" priority="1">
    <xsl:variable name="pos">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:attribute name="r{$pos}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@string"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I changed the name of your attributes to "r1", "r2", etc., because XML doesn't allow you to start a name with a number.

Answer (score 1):

This might do it, run this following snippet of XSLT when processing the top level `<record>` elements:

```
<xsl:for-each select="record">
    <xsl:attribute name="{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@string" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Essentially this iterates over each sub-`<record>` element and creates an `<xsl:attribute>` element describing the desired attribute. The `position()` function is called to get the relative position within the top level element: 1, 2, 3, etc.

This is not a complete solution; some familiarity with XSLT is assumed.