# Gridview displaying XML file data

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

Trying to use a gridview in asp.net to display a few simple rows of data from an xml file.  I've dropped my gridview on the page and choose xmldatasource but my error is something along the lines that the gridview1 does not have any properties or attributes to generate the columns. What else should I be doing.  Everything that I'm reading says add your xml file add your grid view then add your data source and that will render what is in your file.

Thanks

Here is the xml file

```
    <Employees>
      <Employee>
        <Name>Adams John</Name>
        <Age>35</Age>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <Salary>65000</Salary>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
        <Name>Mary Jane</Name>
        <Age>35</Age>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Salary>75000</Salary>
      </Employee>
    </Employee>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar question on SO.

[Gridview binding to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988813/gridview-binding-to-xml?rq=1)

I think you'll find the right solution on a thread referenced above.

Regards,
Uros

Answer (score 1):

As Quoted from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163669.aspx)

The simplest possible solution is to load the XML into a DataSet and bind to that. Another solution would be to use XML serialization to create an object graph from the XML and bind to that. To bind to the raw XML, you would need to create wrapper classes that implement ITypedList, IBindingList, and ICustomTypeDescriptor.

Alternatively, you can try this..

```
 XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Xml_FilePath",new XmlReaderSettings());
 DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

 dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);

 dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Employees"];
 dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        DataSet dsresult = new DataSet();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<Employees><Employee><Name>Adams John</Name><Age>35</Age><Gender>M</Gender><Salary>65000</Salary></Employee><Employee><Name>Mary Jane</Name> <Age>35</Age><Gender>F</Gender><Salary>75000</Salary></Employee></Employees>");
        XmlElement exelement = doc.DocumentElement;
        if (exelement != null)
        {
            XmlNodeReader nodereader = new XmlNodeReader(exelement);
            dsresult.ReadXml(nodereader, XmlReadMode.Auto);
            GridView1.DataSource = dsresult;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```