# How to convert XMLDocument type to string in order to show the result in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument, weather-api

I'm trying to show weather information on my website from world weather online. I'm using VS2012 with c# to create this.

I could able to retrieve data from world weather online to a function under a XMLDocument type variable "WP_XMLdoc".

Take a look at the code below:

```
public static XmlDocument WeatherAPI(string sLocation)
{
    HttpWebRequest WP_Request;
    HttpWebResponse WP_Response = null;
    XmlDocument WP_XMLdoc = null;
    String Value;

    string sKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //The API key generated by World Weather Online
    string sRequestUrl = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?format=xml&"; //The request URL for XML format

    try
    {
        //Here we are concatenating the parameters
        WP_Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(sRequestUrl + "q=" + sLocation + "&key=" + sKey));
        WP_Request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.4) Gecko/20070515 Firefox/2.0.0.4";
        //Making the request
        WP_Response = (HttpWebResponse)WP_Request.GetResponse();
        WP_XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
        //Assigning the response to our XML object
        WP_XMLdoc.Load(WP_Response.GetResponseStream());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    WP_Response.Close();
    return WP_XMLdoc;

    }

}
```

So, now I just want to take XML data from "WP_XMLdoc" variable and show few details like temp_c, windspeed, time etc in my labels.
How can I do that?

The XML data that rest under "WP_XMLdoc" is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <request>
        <type>City</type>
        <query>London, United Kingdom</query>
    </request>
    <current_condition>
        <observation_time>04:17 AM</observation_time>
        <temp_C>17</temp_C>
        <temp_F>63</temp_F>
        <weatherCode>143</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl>
            <![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0006_mist.png]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>
        <weatherDesc>
            <![CDATA[Mist]]>
        </weatherDesc>
        <windspeedMiles>0</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>0</windspeedKmph>
        <winddirDegree>62</winddirDegree>
        <winddir16Point>ENE</winddir16Point>
        <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
        <humidity>94</humidity>
        <visibility>2</visibility>
        <pressure>1010</pressure>
        <cloudcover>50</cloudcover>
    </current_condition>
    <weather>
        <date>2014-09-19</date>
        <tempMaxC>28</tempMaxC>
        <tempMaxF>82</tempMaxF>
        <tempMinC>14</tempMinC>
        <tempMinF>57</tempMinF>
        <windspeedMiles>5</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>8</windspeedKmph>
        <winddirection>SSE</winddirection>
        <winddir16Point>SSE</winddir16Point>
        <winddirDegree>149</winddirDegree>
        <weatherCode>356</weatherCode>
        <weatherIconUrl>
            <![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0010_heavy_rain_showers.png]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>
        <weatherDesc>
            <![CDATA[Moderate or heavy rain shower]]>
        </weatherDesc>
        <precipMM>8.3</precipMM>
    </weather>
</data>
```

Please help!

Comment: How do you want to show it in the label? Just a dump of your XML or values in each node?

Comment: If you look at the xml code. I just want to show few information on screen like /data/current_condition/temp_c, /data/current_condition/windspeedKmph, /data/current_condition/cloudcover etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your existing code successfully load the XML data to `XmlDocument` object, we can then use [`SelectSingleNode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) passing suitable XPath expression as argument to get any particular part of the XML document. For example, to get `<temp_C>` value :

```
string temp_c = WP_XMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("/data/current_condition/temp_C")
                         .InnerText;
```

Another option is using newer XML API, `XDocument`. It has `Load()` method which functionality is similar to `XmlDocument.Load()` :

```
XDocument WP_XMLdoc = XDocument.Load(WP_Response.GetResponseStream());
```

Using this approach, we can simply cast `XElement` to `string` to get it's value :

```
string temp_c = (string)WP_XMLdoc.XPathSelectElement("/data/current_condition/temp_C");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, as an example:

```
var str = @"<your xml here>";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
var output = new List<string>();

foreach (var element in xdoc.Element("data").Element("current_condition").Elements())
{
    output.Add(string.Format("{0} : {1}",element.Name, element.Value.ToString()));
}
```

This would traverse the properties of the current_condition node, you can adjust as necessary to extract what you need.

Comment: The xml values are resting under WP_XMLdoc. Is there any way to take value from it or convert WP_XMLdoc to string and take desired value from it and show in the label??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to your answer in comments I believe you need to show multiple columns of data.

Best option would be to use a `GridView` to populate your `XML` data using ADO.net. It's bit easy.

Have a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988813/gridview-binding-to-xml?rq=1)

Comment: No not like that.... I just want to show few values from the XML to desired label.

I want some like this:
lblTemp.Text = XMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName.temp_c
lblwind.Text = XMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName.windspeed_kmph