# Change position of a node using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am using identity transformation and during this based on a condition, I need to change the position of a node using XSLT.
Suppose, I have an XML like the one:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b1>SampleB1</b1>
        <b2>
            <c1>zyx</c1>
            <c2>wvu</c2>
            <c3>tsr</c3>
            <c4>dtg</c4>
            <c5>hkj</c5>
        </b2>
        <b3>SampleB3</b3>
    </a>
</root>
```

Then I want to change the position of nodes 'c4' & 'c5' and want output as:

```
<root>
    <c4>dtg</c4>
    <c5>hkj</c5>
    <a>
        <b1>SampleB1</b1>
        <b2>
            <c1>zyx</c1>
            <c2>wvu</c2>
            <c3>tsr</c3>
        </b2>
        <b3>SampleB3</b3>
    </a>
</root>
```

Can anyone please tell me, how can we do this. 
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rearrange, you need to adjust your XSL so that it copies what you wants in the order and location that you want it. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- At the root element, recurse through any descendant c4 or c5 nodes first -->
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//c4|//c5"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- At the b2 element, copy everything but the C4 or C5 nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="b2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::c4|self::c5)]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It would be better `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::c4|self::c5)]|@*"/>` for `b2` rule's content template.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- By default, recursively copy all nodes unchanged -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- But don't copy root/a/b2/c3 and root/a/b2/c4 -->
  <xsl:template match="root/a/b2/c3" />
  <xsl:template match="root/a/b2/c4" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Place a copy of a/b2/c3 and a/b2/c4 at the start of root -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="a/b2/c3" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="a/b2/c4" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key to understanding the above is that its not *moving* elements so much as *copying* elements, and then skipping them elsewhere.  Unfortunately this means that we need to specify the elements to move twice (once to skip them and then once again to include a copy of them elsewhere), but at the moment I can't think of a neater way.

This question - [Move sub nodes into parent attributes with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875900/move-sub-nodes-into-parent-attributes-with-xslt)  might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Kragen!!! Your solution doesn't work in my case as I am updating root node and parent node as well.

Answer (score 1):

Pure pull style:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="search"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="c4|c5"/>
    <xsl:template match="c4|c5" mode="search">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="search"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <c4>dtg</c4>
    <c5>hkj</c5>
    <a>
        <b1>SampleB1</b1>
        <b2>
            <c1>zyx</c1>
            <c2>wvu</c2>
            <c3>tsr</c3>
        </b2>
        <b3>SampleB3</b3>
    </a>
</root>
```